# Why when i use dup2() before fork() it doesn't work?

Tags: c, shell, fork, dup2

I want to make a shell and i want to handle multiple pipe. I tried to understand how works dup2() and fork. Normally, fork(), create a new child process who is exactly the same as the father. But when i use dup2 before the fork it doesn't seem to works how i things it should do. But when i use dup2() in the child process it works... I don't understand because normally fork create a copy of the calling process...

Can someone explain why?

This does not work:

```
int fd = open("toto.txt", O_RDONLY);
char str[10] = {0};
int test[2] = {0, 0};
char *av[] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};

pipe(test);
dup2(test[1], 1);
if (fork() == 0) {
    execve(av[0], av, env);
}
else {
    wait(NULL);
    read(test[0], str, 10);
    write(1, str, 10);
}
```

but this works :

```
int fd = open("toto.txt", O_RDONLY);
char str[10] = {0};
int test[2] = {0, 0};
char *av[] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};

pipe(test);
if (fork() == 0) {
    dup2(test[1], 1);
    execve(av[0], av, env);
}
else {
    wait(NULL);
    read(test[0], str, 10);
    write(1, str, 10);
}
```

Comment: What is the one that doesn't work supposed to do?

Comment: The first one is supposed to work but i don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: Define *work*. What is it supposed to be doing that it's not? What is it doing instead?

Comment: It supposed to display on the terminal the 10 first character of my ls command but it doing nothing. It's because i do the dup2() before the fork but i don't understand why it doesn't work in this case

Comment: How do you know if it works or not?  You don't check the return value.

Comment: Why would you expect your first one to display anything on the terminal? You change what standard output (FD 1) goes to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original does not work correctly because:

> ```
> dup2(test[1], 1);
> if (fork() == 0) {
>     execve(av[0], av, env);
> }
> else {
>     wait(NULL);
>     read(test[0], str, 10);
>     write(1, str, 10);
> }
> ```

After the `dup2` stdout is redirected to the pipe. This redirection applies both to the parent and the child. Due to that, the line:

> ```
>     write(1, str, 10);
> ```

writes its data back to the pipe, not the original stdout (which is lost).

By moving the `dup2` to after the `fork()`, and only to the child process, the original stdout of the parent is left alone. In that case only the child's stdout gets redirected.

Note: calling `wait` before reading the pipe will work for small pipe traffic like in the example, but won't work for big traffic. The issue is that the pipe has a limited buffer. Once the buffer is full, the pipe starts to block writes. The `wait` will wait on the child to finish, but the child will wait on the pipe to be read by the parent. This can become a deadlock when the traffic is big enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! What i need to do to handle big traffic ?

Comment: @Progear yes, to handle big traffic you must read the pipe before waiting for the child to finish. In your case, replace `read` and `wait`